# Why document.write is not working with dynamically loaded script?

Tags: javascript, dom, asynchronous

Im little bit confused about this behavior.
The situation is: we have a rendered document. [The specifiaction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write) says, that it will clear out current document, if we run this method when document is rendered. I run this in console:

```
document.write("Hi!")
```

and get empty document with "Hi!" text.

But the same code in the dynamically and asynchronously loaded script do nothing:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = "some/path/test.js"
s.type = "text/javascript";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
```

test.js contains:

```
document.write("Hi!")
```

I know, that i can redefine document.write and etc. I just asking about the specification - where this behaviour is specified?

Thank you!

Comment: the only problen here is the invalid url you use, just change the `.../test.js` to `../test.js`

Comment: No, there just abstract path :) problem is not there.

Comment: I just tried the exact same thing and after injecting the test.js everything got wiped out except the `Hi`. try putting a simple alert in the test.js then check if it is called.

Comment: Try inject test.js in setTimeout wrapper.

Comment: So, did u mean that test.js is load, but "Hi" is not appear? If yes, my question is exact about this behavior :)

Answer (score 0):

Just found some info at [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script):

> Never call document.write() from an async script. In Gecko 1.9.2, calling document.write() has an unpredictable effect. In Gecko 2.0, calling document.write() from an async script has no effect (other than printing a warning to the error console).